# Copy remote data into local database

Tags: php, mysql

Can anybody help me to copy all data from remote server mysql database to local database. I am using the following code.

```
$command="mysql -h {$mysql_host} -u '{$mysql_username}' -p '{$mysql_password}'  '{$filename}' < '{$mysql_database}'"; 
$output = shell_exec($command);
```

Comment: And what's your current error?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
mysqldump -h remote_host -u remote_user -premote_password remote_database | mysql -u local_user -plocal_password local_database
```

It's dumping database from remote host, and then pipe'ing output to your mysql.

In your code it'll be:

```
$command="mysqldump -h {$mysql_host} -u '{$mysql_username}' -p'{$mysql_password}' '{$filename}' | mysql -u '{$local_user}' -p'{$local_password}' {$local_database}";
$output = shell_exec($command);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `mysqldump -h "REMOTE_HOST" -u'REMOTE_USER' -p'REMOTE_PASSWORD' REMOTE_DB_NAME > /PATH_TO/back_ups/back_up.sql` then just find this dump by the path in the catalog

```
$command="mysqldump -h {$mysql_host} -u '{$mysql_username}' -p '{$mysql_password}'  {$mysql_database} > '{$filename}'";
```

`{$mysql_database}` without `''`